# Switching from one thread to another in a cycle (java)

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's my problem : while programming a little software that will make fireworks appear in java, I chose to give each fuse in the firework a thread. Now, I have a LinkedList of fuses that each have a thread, and those threads all consist in waiting a certain time, then drawing a fuse diameter by diameter to get to that kind of look :

[A red fuse drawn normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E80x.png)

The fuse stays on for a while, then it is painted over in black and the thread is stopped.

The thing is, since all the threads are started together, they keep overlapping and drawing stuff with each other's colors or positions, causing my fuses to look like this :

[A pink fuse drawn while a green one was running too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDUgj.png)

I am trying to find a way to give each thread a few seconds to draw one diameter, then stop it and go over to the next one, and that in cycles so that all diameters can be drawn one after the other (the explosion effect is much prettier that way than if you draw the whole fuse at once). That way, there would only be one active thread at a time, but they would all regularly get a chance to do something. I tried a few different methods and I put the best one here, but even that doesn't fully work ! If any of you had an idea how to go through a list of threads a certain number of times, giving them each a few seconds and then going around again, that would be just great !!

```
public void peindre(Graphics gr){       
            gr.setColor(Color.black);
            gr.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
            for (Fusee fus : fusees) {
                fus.g = gr ;
                if (fus.num > numMax){
                    numMax = fus.num ; 
                }
                if (fus.puissEtincelles > puissEtincellesMax){
                    puissEtincellesMax = fus.puissEtincelles ; 
                fus.anim.start(); 
            }
            for (int k = 1; k<=puissEtincellesMax ; k++ ){  //k is the number of diameters drawn
                int i =1 ;  
                if (i != numMax) {
                    for (Fusee fus : fusees) {
                        if (fus.num != i) {  
                            try {
                                fus.anim.wait();
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                                System.out.println(e);
                            }
                    i += 1 ;   
                }
                }
                }
                else if (i==numMax){
                    i = 1 ; 
            }   
        }
    }
```

(And here's the simplified run() to what the threads actually do)

```
    public void run(){                  
    while (true){
    if (active == true){
        if (tpsDepart == 0) {
          if (duree>0){ 
                 duree = duree-1 ;
                 peindreFusee(g) ;
                 if (k<puissEtincelles) {
                    k+=1 ;
                    }
          }
          else if (duree == 0){
             active = false ; 
          }
        }
        else if (tpsDepart >0){
            tpsDepart = tpsDepart - 1 ; 
        }
    }
    else if (active == false){  
        couleur = Color.black ; 
        peindreFuseeFin(g) ;
        anim.stop(); 
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(600);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't want threads; you really want sequential, linear processing.  Perhaps the mistake was assuming that threads were the right way to do it.

Comment: If you just want to do things sequentially in a fixed order, you don't need threads.

Comment: You can start n threads and stop/start them from a single loop using the standard Thread class. Google can tell you how.

Comment: Would a timer based solution not be better? where every explosion starts at some time and place and at every clock tick draw at a bit longer distance from the origin.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes I guess a time based solution would make sense, I don't know how to program that kind of thing though ! It's the first time I'm programing with threads and I was simply told they were the best way to take care of my fuses which is why I've started to use them... But how do you program a clock that runs independently so that every fuse can read its value ?

Comment: There is one timer, the "clock" which at every tick notifies all fuses of the tick. Every fuse  maintains its own  tick counter and finally removes itself.  For nice effects one could draw line pieces, even with two gradients : dark to light color.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly you want your programm to behave sequential/linear. Every Fuse in your list is processed sequential:

Fuse 1 > Fuse 2 > Fuse 3 > Fuse 4 > ...

You do not need Threads to achieve this behaviour. Threads run concurrent. So as you said they can and will overlap each other (they will execute whenever your CPU feels like it). By running threads and force them do sequential stuff you would basically "destroy" everything a thread offers you.

If you still want to use threads you could `synchronize` them by using the `synchronize` keyword like this:

```
//Your run method
public void run()
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        //Your code in the run method
    }
}
```

Everything inside the `synchronize` Block can only be processed by 1 Thread at a time. All other threads will wait untill the currently processing thread finished its work.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++EDIT+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Well, there is actually an Interface, which lets you Schedule the execution of `Runnables`. It's included in `java.util.concurrent` and called `ScheduledExecutorService`.

The method you could use for your kind of task would be `scheduleAtFixedRate(...)`. It enables you to run a periodic action that starts with an initial delay.

```
//First, lets create the scheduler. Replace NUM_OF_FUSES with the actual number
//or in your case the size of the fuse-List
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUM_OF_FUSES);

//Now we add all of your fuses (aka. Runnables/Threads) into this pool
//(assuming your List of fuses is called 'fuselist' and each 'Fuse'
//is 'Runnable')
long delay = 0;
long repeat = 3;
for(Fuse fuse: fuselist)
{
    //What this does is:
    //It adds each of your threads to the pool. Each thread kicks of with a certain delay. The
    //first on kicks right off, since the delay is 0, the second kicks off after 1 second ...
    //After the thread has done its work it will repeat itself after 3 seconds.
    //.scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable runnable,long delay,long repeat, TimeUnit unit)
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(fuse, delay, repeat, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    delay++;
}

//To stop all of your threads you'd call...
//...to let your threads finish their work
scheduler.shutdown();

//...or this to stop them right now, without waiting for each Thread to finish thw work
scheduler.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @NateStone, however I'm afraid that if I synchronize the fuses will not be able to explode at the same time since only one thread will be able to access the graphic environment... Actually I just want those different fuses to be able to explode simultaneously but in different threads that each keep their own color. Which is why I was thinking of going through the list of threads and activating one for a few seconds, then the next one, and going like that through the whole liste a certain number of times... I hope that's clearer I'm sorry it's hard to explain !